# animate() scroll not working with href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slideshow scrolling image by image with jQuery. 
When I add `<a href="#">`, the slideshow stop effect.

Can you help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = $("#container");
    var height = container.height();
    var children = container.children();
    var len = children.size();
    var i = 0;

    children.each(function(i,e){$(e).css('z-index', len - i);});

    var animate = function()
    {
        var img = children.eq(i);
        var prev = i == 0 ? children.eq(len - 1) : children.eq(i - 1);
        prev.css('opacity', 1);
        i = i == len - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
        var next = children.eq(i);
        var top = img.height() - height;
        img.css('z-index', len);
        next.css('z-index', len - 1);
        next.css('opacity', 1);
        next.show();
        img.animate({top: -top}, 2000, "swing", function(){
            img.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                img.css('z-index', 0);
                img.css('top', 0);
                animate();
            }); 
        });
    }

    animate();
});
```

My script: http://jsfiddle.net/d4n7dcnf/12/

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the images with `<a href="#">` then you need to change the line 12 of your css for `#container > a`. See a fork of your script: http://jsfiddle.net/jt1vhk4d/